# Trouble uploading file to google cloud storage

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, graphql, google-cloud-storage

I am having an issue trying to upload a file to Google Cloud Storage. I am getting the error `ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'file.extension'`. My current implementation looks like this:

```
const { Storage } = require('@google-cloud/storage');

const storage = new Storage();
const bucketName = 'bucket-name';

exports.uploadFileGCP = async (file, anchorID) => {
    const { filename, mimetype, encoding, createReadStream } = await file
    await storage.bucket(bucketName).upload(filename, {
        destination: `anchor/${anchorID}/` + filename,
        predefinedAcl: 'publicRead',
        metadata: {
            cacheControl: 'no-cache'
        },
    });

    console.log(`${filename} uploaded to ${bucketName}`)
}
```

Looking through the documentation, it appears that the `filename` in the `upload` portion requires a path to the file on the local machine. I can't seem to find a solution in which I can upload the file without using a local path. Is there a way to do that?

This is the code for my GraphQL resolver where the file is coming through:

```
async function uploadFile(parent, args, ctx, info) {

    const google = await uploadFileGCP(args.file, args.anchorID);
    console.log(google)
    ...
}
```

I feel like I'm missing something obvious but, can't quite figure out what's going on. Thank you for any help on the matter.

Comment: Can you clarify the problem?  Do you have a local file local to the application that is performing the GCS upload?  Where do you expect to get the file data that you wish to upload from?

Comment: I am currently attempting to upload via postman by selecting a file on my local machine and trying to send it to google storage. Eventually, this implementation will be plugged in to my companies cv app where they will be sending file data to be stored in the cloud. The files will not be stored in the application itself. Basically, it needs to be a dynamic solution where the files can come from multiple locations.

Comment: I think you want to use the following API to stream data to a GCS object (File).  See .. https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/File.html#createWriteStream

Comment: hey @seanulus , as Kolban said , use createWriteStream : `bucketName.file(filename).createWriteStream({resumable: false, gzip: true})`

Comment: @Methkal Khalawi @Kolban Thanks. I ended up being able to upload with that method. I'm curious if there is a way to create a file system in the bucket upon upload similar to AWS. Example `anchor/id/file`. If you happen to know a way to do that, I'd much appreciate it.

Comment: hey @seanulus, as the solution worked for you, I created an answer here. Can you please accept it for the community benefits.

Answer (score 1):

as @Kolban said you should use createWriteStream :

```
bucketName.file(filename).createWriteStream({resumable: false, gzip: true})
```

Comment: that link helped me, I had to use the ```fs.createReadStream```, thanks o/